# How to create a custom route in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, routes

I'm working on this wordpress site and trying to connect this website with an external API.

I need to create a custom route for reading properties, But so far I didn't find an answer.

The URL I'm trying to config is this one:

www.mypage.com/properties/id_description1

And it should point to a php template called (property-single.php).

Answer (score 0):

You could use .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rule for the redirect
RewriteRule ^properties/id_description1$ property-single.php [QSA,L,NC]
```

You can also use dynamic pointers like:

```
RewriteRule ^properties/id/([0-9]+)$ property-single.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

This tool might help you with that: https://www.htaccessredirect.net/